# manifest.jsonで定義されているjsファイルが生成されない

Tags: ruby-on-rails, docker, json, webpack

#### 前提・実現したいこと

Rails 6で、manifest.jsで定義されているファイル名の、jsが生成されません
ビルドしたところ、public/packs以下にcssファイルとjsファイル、manifest.jsonは生成されるのですが、jsファイルだけネームが違います
開発環境では、webpacker_dev_serverを使用することで問題なく機能しているのですが、herokuデプロイ時に、ページを開こうとするとwebpackerのActionView::Template::Errorが出ており、おそらくこのエラーもjsファイルが生成されないことが原因ではないかと思ってます。
manifest.jsonで定義されているファイルと、実際に生成されたファイルが違うというのはわかるのですが、解決方法がわからず苦戦しております。
お心当たりのある方、過去に同様の問題に出会って解決した経験のある方いらっしゃいましたら、ご教授お願いいたします。

#### 該当のソースコード

#### manifest.json

```
{
  "application.css": "/packs/css/application-6e38df4d.css",
  "application.css.map": "/packs/css/application-6e38df4d.css.map",
  "application.js": "/packs/application-c041cdca59b53f1b1ad7.js",
  "application.js.map": "/packs/application-c041cdca59b53f1b1ad7.js.map",
  "entrypoints": {
    "application": {
      "css": [
        "/packs/css/application-6e38df4d.css"
      ],
      "js": [
        "/packs/application-c041cdca59b53f1b1ad7.js"
      ],
      "css.map": [
        "/packs/css/application-6e38df4d.css.map"
      ],
      "js.map": [
        "/packs/application-c041cdca59b53f1b1ad7.js.map"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

#### 上記manifest.jsonで実際に生成されたファイル名

/packs/application-ba3f382ecddda9df7c24.js
/packs/application-ba3f382ecddda9df7c24.js.map

#### webpacker.yml

```
default: &default
  source_path: app/javascript
  source_entry_path: packs
  public_root_path: public
  public_output_path: packs
  cache_path: tmp/cache/webpacker
  check_yarn_integrity: false
  webpack_compile_output: true

  # Additional paths webpack should lookup modules
  # ['app/assets', 'engine/foo/app/assets']
  resolved_paths: []

  # Reload manifest.json on all requests so we reload latest compiled packs
  cache_manifest: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  static_assets_extensions:
    - .jpg
    - .jpeg
    - .png
    - .gif
    - .tiff
    - .ico
    - .svg
    - .eot
    - .otf
    - .ttf
    - .woff
    - .woff2

  extensions:
    - .mjs
    - .js
    - .sass
    - .scss
    - .css
    - .module.sass
    - .module.scss
    - .module.css
    - .png
    - .svg
    - .gif
    - .jpeg
    - .jpg

development:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Verifies that correct packages and versions are installed by inspecting package.json, yarn.lock, and node_modules
  check_yarn_integrity: false

  # Reference: https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/
  dev_server:
    https: false
    host: webpack
    port: 3035
    public: localhost:3035
    hmr: true
    # Inline should be set to true if using HMR
    inline: true
    overlay: true
    compress: true
    disable_host_check: true
    use_local_ip: false
    quiet: false
    pretty: false
    headers:
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    watch_options:
      ignored: '**/node_modules/**'


test:
  <<: *default
  compile: true

  # Compile test packs to a separate directory
  public_output_path: packs-test

production:
  <<: *default

  # Production depends on precompilation of packs prior to booting for performance.
  compile: false

  # Extract and emit a css file
  extract_css: true

  # Cache manifest.json for performance
  cache_manifest: true
```

#### docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3'
services: 

  web: &app_base
    build: .
    command: >
      bash -c "rm -f tmp/pids/server.pid && 
      bundle exec rails s -p 3000 -b '0.0.0.0'" 
    environment:
      WEBPACKER_DEV_SERVER_HOST: webpack
    volumes:
      - .:/docker_dog
      - /docker_dog/node_modules/
    ports:
      - "3000:3000"
      - "1234:1234"
      - "26162:26162"
    depends_on:
      - db
    stdin_open: true
    tty: true

  webpack:
    <<: *app_base
    command: bash -c "rm -rf /app/public/packs && bundle exec rake webpacker:clobber && ./bin/webpack && ./bin/webpack-dev-server "
    ports:
      - 3035:3035
    depends_on:
      - web
```

#### ActionView::Template::Error

```
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543337+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=shielded-ravine-09485.herokuapp.com request_id=00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29 fwd="106.180.11.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=23ms status=500 bytes=1891 protocol=https
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543566+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543567+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29] ActionView::Template::Error (Webpacker can't find application in /docker_dog/public/packs/manifest.json. Possible causes:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543569+00:00 app[web.1]: 1. You want to set webpacker.yml value of compile to true for your environment
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543569+00:00 app[web.1]: unless you are using the `webpack -w` or the webpack-dev-server.
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543570+00:00 app[web.1]: 2. webpack has not yet re-run to reflect updates.
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543570+00:00 app[web.1]: 3. You have misconfigured Webpacker's config/webpacker.yml file.
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543570+00:00 app[web.1]: 4. Your webpack configuration is not creating a manifest.
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543571+00:00 app[web.1]: Your manifest contains:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543572+00:00 app[web.1]: {
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543572+00:00 app[web.1]: }
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543572+00:00 app[web.1]: ):
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543573+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]      6:     <%= csp_meta_tag %>
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543573+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]      7:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543573+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]      8:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543574+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]      9:     <%= stylesheet_pack_tag 'application',  media: 'all', 'data-turbolinks-track': 'reload' %>
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543575+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]     10:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543575+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]     11:   </head>
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543575+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]     12:
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543578+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29]
2020-05-24T11:30:47.543579+00:00 app[web.1]: [00fcd501-ecff-47db-b9d9-63268e4a0a29] app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:9
2020-05-24T11:30:48.106231+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=shielded-ravine-09485.herokuapp.com request_id=7c66779c-2470-4038-bae2-a2e4a1e23538 fwd="106.180.11.35" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=11ms status=200 bytes=207 protocol=https
```

#### 試したこと

$bundle exec rake webpacker:clobber

docker-compose.ymlのwebpackのコマンドにbundle exec rake webpacker:clobber && ./bin/webpack
を追加

#### 補足情報（FW/ツールのバージョンなど）

ruby '2.7.0'
Rails '6.0.2.2'
yarn '1.22.4'
webpacker '4.2.2'

Comment: 「webpackerのActionView::Template::Error」のエラーログの詳細があると回答できるかもしれません。

Comment: ご回答いただきありがとうございます。こちらのサイト初めて使用しましたため、返答見落としておりました。herokuのエラーログ追加させていただきます。ご確認よろしくお願いいたします。